# Unreachable code android in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i am "attempting" to make an android app. I am trying to make it so that when i create a

spinner   if...else is  suddenly show "error message"  `Unreachable code`

Code:

```
Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

ArrayAdapter localArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.arr);

localArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

localSpinner.setAdapter(localArrayAdapter);

localSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()

{

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id)
  {
    if (pos == 0)
    {
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    }
    do
    {
      return;
      if (pos == 1)
      {
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
      }
      if (pos == 2)
      {
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
      }
      if (pos == 3)
      {
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
      }
      if (pos == 4)
      {
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
      }
    }

    while (pos != 5);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab31)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab32)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab33)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab34)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab35)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ((LinearLayout)MainKasama.this.findViewById(R.id.tab36)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

I have one more question  in my code

code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;

final AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

have a error message  `AlertDialog cannot be resolved to a type`  how do i fix that error

thank you for answering my questions

Answer (score 2):

```
do
{
  return;  // remove this return 
  if (pos == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Pulkit Sethi is correct but he didn't provide any reason as to why you have to remove that `return`. You might have inserted a `return` there mistakenly or you might not know what that `return` will do. I am considering latter as the case and thus providing the explanation.

Whenever a compiler, in any programming language, gets a `return`, it immediately exits the loop and all the statements below are not executed. This is the reason why you are getting **Unreachable code android in spinner**.

Answer (score 0):

Where, in your activity, is this code: 
final AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

check if it is inside a listener or somewhere else, assign "context=this;" in oncreate or onresume of your activity

The "this" for AlertDialog.Builder might not be context